# How to copy and replace files in Apple Automator, while retaining folder structure?

Tags: macos, automator

I have two folders that have similar sub-folder structures.  I need to copy, not sync, the files from one in to the other, replace any existing files if they are present in the destination folder, and keep the sub-folder hierarchy.

For example, starting with this:

```
/source_folder/stuff/sub_one/file1.txt
/source_folder/stuff/sub_one/file2.txt
/source_folder/stuff/sub_two/file3.txt

/destination_folder/stuff/sub_one/file1.txt
/destination_folder/stuff/sub_one/file9.txt
/destination_folder/stuff/sub_three/file4.txt
```

After copying:

```
/source_folder/stuff/sub_one/file1.txt
/source_folder/stuff/sub_one/file2.txt
/source_folder/stuff/sub_two/file3.txt

/destination_folder/stuff/sub_one/file1.txt (replaced by copy in source_folder)
/destination_folder/stuff/sub_one/file2.txt (added from copy in source_folder)
/destination_folder/stuff/sub_one/file9.txt
/destination_folder/stuff/sub_two/file3.txt (added from copy in source_folder)
/destination_folder/stuff/sub_three/file4.txt
```

I've created the following Auotmator project, but the files are all copied to the root of the destination folder.

[image]

Any recommendations on how to accomplish this in Apple Automator?

Comment: It looks like calling "sync -RI" would solve this problem.  I'm continuing to explore.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following works.

Add a "Run AppleScript" action in Automator, then add the following script:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Finder"

        set source to choose folder with prompt "Choose source folder"
        set destination to choose folder with prompt "Choose destination folder"

        do shell script "rsync -rI " & POSIX path of source & space & POSIX path of destination

    end tell

    return input
end run
```